# React-Native not building application, showing module not found error

Tags: react-native

When I'm trying to run react-native run-android I'm getting this error.

App.js code

> import React, {Component} from 'react'; import {Platform, StyleSheet,
>   Text, View} from 'react-native'; import { createStackNavigation } from
>   'react-navigation'; import Splash from './components/splash/splash';
>   import Login from './components/login/login';
>
> const App = createStackNavigation({
>       Login: {screen: Login},
>       Spash: {screen: Splash} },{
>       initialRouteName: "Splash",
>       headerMode: "none", });
>
> export default App

**Unable to resolve module `./components/splash/splash` from `/home/subrata/puplr_mobile_app/puplr/App.js`: The module `./components/splash/splash` could not be found from `/home/subrata/puplr_mobile_app/puplr/App.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
  * `/home/subrata/puplr_mobile_app/puplr/components/splash/splash(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
  * `/home/subrata/puplr_mobile_app/puplr/components/splash/splash/index(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
Error: Unable to resolve module `./components/splash/splash` from `/home/subrata/puplr_mobile_app/puplr/App.js`: The module `./components/splash/splash` could not be found from `/home/subrata/puplr_mobile_app/puplr/App.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
  * `/home/subrata/puplr_mobile_app/puplr/components/splash/splash(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
  * `/home/subrata/puplr_mobile_app/puplr/components/splash/splash/index(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/home/subrata/puplr_mobile_app/puplr/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:120:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/home/subrata/puplr_mobile_app/puplr/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:49:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/home/subrata/puplr_mobile_app/puplr/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:218:16)
    at Object.resolve (/home/subrata/puplr_mobile_app/puplr/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:141:30)
    at dependencies.map.result (/home/subrata/puplr_mobile_app/puplr/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:373:31)
    at Array.map ()
    at resolveDependencies (/home/subrata/puplr_mobile_app/puplr/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:369:18)
    at /home/subrata/puplr_mobile_app/puplr/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:188:33
    at Generator.next ()
    at step (/home/subrata/puplr_mobile_app/puplr/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:298:30)**

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you may need to restart the Metro bundler for it to find a newly created file.

If it isn't your issue, you have to make sure that you do have a `splash.js` file in your `/home/subrata/puplr_mobile_app/puplr/components/splash` folder.